# How to access argument properties when writing custom NHibernate HQL generator

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hql, expression, linq-expressions

I have the following custom type with a method on it to determine if one span of time overlaps another

```
public struct DateTimeSpan
{
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }

    public bool Overlaps(DateTimeSpan overlap)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a custom HQL generator so that when I use this method within my data access LINQ queries it will generate to appropriate SQL when querying the database.

This is the start of my `BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod` that attempts to compare the `End` property of one `DateTimeSpan` with the other

```
public class DateSpanOverlapsDateTimeSpanHqlGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public DateSpanOverlapsDateTimeSpanHqlGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[]
            {
                ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<DateTimeSpan>(x => x.Overlaps(new DateTimeSpan()))
            };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder builder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        var endTargetProperty = ReflectionHelper.GetProperty<DateTimeSpan, DateTime?>(x => x.End);
        Expression endTargetExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(targetObject, endTargetProperty);

        var endArgumentProperty = ReflectionHelper.GetProperty<DateTimeSpan, DateTime?>(x => x.End);
        Expression endArgumentExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(arguments[0], endArgumentProperty);

       return builder.GreaterThanOrEqual(visitor.Visit(endTargetExpression).AsExpression(), visitor.Visit(endArgumentExpression).AsExpression());
    }
}
```

I have proven that the `End` property in the `targetObject` is being evaluated fine but no matter what I do I cannot get it to evaluate the `End` property in `arguments[0]`.  The above code is just one example of what I have tried (and seems the most obvious given it works for the `targetObject`) with most things I try ending up with the exception `Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException`

One obvious different between `targetObject` and `arguments[0]` is that `targetObject` is of type `PropertyExpression` and `arguments[0]` is of type `ConstantExpression`.  I assume this means there needs to be different ways to access them but I cannot work out what it is!

Answer (score 2):

treeBuilder.Constant(arg.SubProperty); will cache your object so you will end up to have problem when you will run your query.

you should add an overload into your DateTimeSpan

```
public bool Overlaps(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
```

match the signature into your DateSpanOverlapsDateTimeSpanHqlGenerator

```
SupportedMethods = new[]
{
ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<DateTimeSpan>(span => span.Overlaps(default(DateTime?), default(DateTime?)))
};
```

and get the values in this way:

```
public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder builder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
{
    var startProperty = ReflectionHelper.GetProperty<DateTimeSpan, DateTime?>(x => x.Start);
    var endProperty = ReflectionHelper.GetProperty<DateTimeSpan, DateTime?>(x => x.End);

    MemberExpression targetStartExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(targetObject, startProperty);
    MemberExpression targetEndExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(targetObject, endProperty);

    HqlExpression startDateExpression = visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression();
    HqlExpression endDateExpression = visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression();
    ....
}
```

after that business as usual:

```
builder.LessThanOrEqual(visitor.Visit(targetStartExpression).AsExpression(), endDateExpression)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever resolved this or are still interested in an answer, however I stumbled across this question myself while looking for a solution to this exact problem, so thought I would add my solution for others.

While debugging I noticed that the target object parameter is passed in as an expression of type `PropertyExpression`, whereas my argument was passed in as a type of `ConstantExpression`, so while it's perfectly valid to add to `PropertyExpression` using `Expression.Property`, that doesn't work with a constant value.

Instead I extract the value of the constant and access the values of sub-properties directly, creating new constant expressions which I can then use to build the query expression.

I don't know if this is the best, or most elegant way to do it, but it worked for me. I hope it helps.

```
 public class MyObject
 {
    public double SubProperty { get; set; }
 }

 private HqlTreeNode GenerateHQL(
    MethodInfo method,
    Expression targetObject,
    ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments,
    HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder,
    IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
{
    MyObject arg = (MyObject)((ConstantExpression)arguments[0]).Value;
    HqlConstant argExpression = treeBuilder.Constant(arg.SubProperty);

    ...
    ...
}
```